# Cannot create shared memory for key 12345: File exists

Tags: memory, shared, yad

When I run some script using yad notebook, I get this error:

```
$ ./example.sh
yad: cannot create shared memory for key 12345: File exists
```

After rebooting, it was good for a few times; but now, it happens every time.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Use ipcs/ipcrm; ipcs will list the shared memory resources and ipcrm will remove them. They should be in the util-linux package or similar.

In general it is probably safe to just run 'ipcrm --all=shm' should work. That deletes all the shared memory segments, but only if there are no references to them. So it shouldn't delete things out from under other programs. At least that is my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`ipcrm -M 12345`

"to remove shared memory segment by key", source:

`ipcrm --help`

You can use `ipcs` to list the shared memory resources, if you need some informations.